# How can I query a dictionary that is a value in my database?

Tags: sql, postgresql, dictionary

I am working with a PostgreSQL database (Dbeaver), and I have a dictionary as one of the values in one of the columns, how can I query the dictionary?

Say for instance, the column name is `info`, and the table name is `table`, and we have the following dictionary:

```
names = {1: 'Patrick', 2: 'Dom', 3: 'Lily'}
```

Let's say I want to query the dictionary for 'Patrick', how would I do this?

I imagine it would be something like:

```
SELECT info FROM table where ...
```

Comment: Column info data type?

Comment: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-json/

Comment: What is the data type of that column? Looks like an attempt to use something similar to JSON, but that's not valid JSON.

Comment: Postgres does not have a dictionary type, that is Python. As others have said that looks like an attempt at a JSON object. Whether it is being stored as `json` or `jsonb` will determine the solution to the problem.